# C# - Convert HTML unordered list to JSON array

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, json

I'd like to convert an unordered list, which is stored as a `string` into a JSON array.

The reason I need this is because I'm screen scraping a website (with permission) so all I've got is website source stored as a `string` (yes, it's horrible) until they finish their API (and yes, they've agreed not to change any of their HTML in the process). :-)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="column">
  <li><a href="/view.php?m=48902&g=313433">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/view.php?m=09844&g=313433">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/view.php?m=23473&g=313433">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JSON:**

```
{"items":[
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "/view.php?m=48902&g=313433",
            name: "Item 1",
            m: 48902,
            g: 313433
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            url: "/view.php?m=09844&g=313433",
            name: "Item 2",
            m: 09844,
            g: 313433
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            url: "/view.php?m=23473&g=313433",
            name: "Item 3",
            m: 23473,
            g: 313433
        }
]}
```

Comment: I don't think you should do this conversion at server-side, use jQuery and achieve it at client-side.

Comment: Why do you need to do this server-side?

Comment: @Paperjam: I'm screen scraping a website (with permission) so all I've got is website source stored as a string (yes, it's horrible).

Comment: @Braveyard: See updated question with reasons why.

Comment: @Fulvio and in what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @Icarus: I need to convert an unordered HTML list into a JSON array with various different values originally contained within the list items as properties in the array.

Comment: @Fluvio it makes sense but it is not clear what part you find difficult to do. I will post an answer with some pointers & pseudo code hoping that it gives you some idea.

Comment: @Icarus: I guess I'm not quite sure how to grab certain values from each list item and construct the JSON with the correct values and properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposed approach:

Since you will be parsing HTML extensively, I recommend that you download [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and use it to parse your HTML. There is some sample code in the website. It also supports LINQ, so parsing the HTML should be relatively easy.

As far as converting to JSON, my advise is that you create a class with the structure you want; for example:

```
public class MyItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int g { get; set; }
        public int m { get; set; }
    }
```

Now that you have the structure ready as a class, you can build a `List<MyItem>` with all the elements you parsed from your HTML.

The final step to convert to JSON is a matter of doing:

```
List<MyItem> list = .... the list constructed
JavascriptSerializer js = new JavascriptSerializer();
string jsonOutput = js.Serialize(list);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to use the HTMLAgilityPack to do what I need. Perfect.

Comment: As for the JSON conversion, in addition to what Icarus offered, I would like tell this library: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you're screen scraping, I would recommend using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to read the HTML (using XPath), then either use a JSON library such as [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) or use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer) class to serialize the HAP object into JSON.